# How to use refresh token with fastapi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jwt, fastapi

I'm trying to find an example of using the [refresh token](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) in fastapi.
The fastapi [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/) provides an example of how to create a bearer token with a limited lifetime but not how to refresh the token.

For flask there is [flask-jwt-extended](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/refresh_tokens/?highlight=refresh) but didn't find something similar for fastapi.

Any suggestions will be appreciated thx!

Comment: I believe that either your client should ask after a while for the new token or simply at each new request, extend the response content with the new token

Answer (score 14):

You might wanna check out [fastapi-jwt-auth](https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/usage/refresh/). It is inspired by flask-jwt-extended. There is a good documentation on how to use the refresh token with good [examples](https://indominusbyte.github.io/fastapi-jwt-auth/usage/refresh/).

First you need to install the package: `pip install fastapi-jwt-auth`. And configure the secret.
Then on the login create a refresh token and access token and return it to the user.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from fastapi_jwt_auth import AuthJWT
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):
    email: str
    password: str

class Settings(BaseModel):
    authjwt_secret_key: str = "secret"

@AuthJWT.load_config
def get_config():
    return Settings()

@app.post('/login')
def login(user: User, Authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    if user.email != "test@test.com" or user.password != "test":
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401,detail="Incorrect email or password")
    access_token = Authorize.create_access_token(subject=user.email)
    refresh_token = Authorize.create_refresh_token(subject=user.email)
    return {"access_token": access_token, "refresh_token": refresh_token}
```

In the next step you should create an Endpoint to refresh the access token.

```py
@app.post('/refresh')
def refresh(Authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    Authorize.jwt_refresh_token_required()
    current_user = Authorize.get_jwt_subject()
    new_access_token = Authorize.create_access_token(subject=current_user)
    return {"access_token": new_access_token}

# Example protected Endpoint
@app.get('/hello')
def refresh(Authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    Authorize.jwt_required()
    return {"hello": "world"}
```

Note this only a small example from a security perspective you should swap the refresh tokens on refresh and blacklist the old token. The library offers therefore the decorator `@AuthJWT.token_in_denylist_loader`. You could implement the blacklist with an in-memory database that keeps invalidated tokens until the expiry date is reached. Also in production choose a real secret.

Comment: repo hasn't been updated since 2020, to solve some issues like [this](https://github.com/IndominusByte/fastapi-jwt-auth/issues/98) you might end up downgrading fastapi and pydantic versions

Comment: fastapi version could be the latest version by pydantic should be downgraded

Answer (score -2):

I generated my own token, according to the time interval between this request and the last request to determine whether to refresh the token, if the time exceeds the scheduled time to replace the token, while notifying the front-end to save the new token