# How to use refresh token to get access token in fastapi

Tags: oauth-2.0, fastapi

I want to implement refresh_token endpoint. However, I am clueless about it, how to use refresh token token to get access token. I have generated refresh token here lie this in login/access-token endpoint. Do I first need to store this refresh token or client has to send it?

I am also unsure whether this is the correct way to generate refresh token below.

```py
@app.post("/login/access-token", response_model=schema.Token)
def login(dbs: Session = Depends(get_db), form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()) -> Any:
    """
    OAuth2 compatible token login, get an access token for future requests
    """
    print('In login')
    user = crud.authenticate(
        dbs, email=form_data.username, password=form_data.password
    )
    # print('In login user', user)

    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect email or password")
    elif not crud.is_active(user):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    userdata = {
        'user_id': user.id,
        'email': user.email,
        'provider_type': user.provider_type,
        'is_active': user.is_active,
        'is_super_user': user.is_super_user
    }

    print('In login after token')
    access_token = security.create_access_token(
        user.id, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )

    refreshdata = {'token_type': 'refresh', 'user_id': user.id}
    refresh_token = security.create_access_token(
        refreshdata, expires_delta=timedelta(days=settings.REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_DAYS)
    )

    # print('refresh_token', refresh_token)

    return {
        # "access_token": security.create_access_token(
        #     user.id, expires_delta=access_token_expires
        # ),
        "access_token": access_token,
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "user": userdata
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413698/how-to-use-refresh-token-with-fastapi

Comment: I saw this solution but problem with this approach is what if my current  access token is expired itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it.

```py
@app.post("/refresh-token", response_model=schema.Token)
def refresh_token(request: schema.TokenItem, dbs: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    refresh_token = request.refresh_token
    # print('refresh_data', refresh_data)

    token_user = crud.get_access_from_refresh_token(dbs, refresh_token = refresh_token)

    login_token = dependencies.create_login_token(user = token_user, refresh_token = refresh_token)

    return login_token

def get_access_from_refresh_token(db: Session, refresh_token: str):
    # print('in get access token', refresh_token)

    payload = jwt.decode(refresh_token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[settings.ALGORITHM])
    token_data = schema.TokenPayload(**payload)
    token_user = get_user(db, user_id=token_data.sub)

    return token_user

def create_login_token(user: models.User, refresh_token: str):
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=settings.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    userdata = {
        'user_id': user.id,
        'email': user.email,
        'provider_type': user.provider_type,
        'is_active': user.is_active,
        'is_super_user': user.is_super_user
    }

    access_token = security.create_access_token(
        user.id, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )

    return {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "user": userdata
    }
```